# Could xsl:variable be defined twice with same name

Tags: variables, xslt, standards

Could xsl:variable be defined twice with same name in same scope. 
For code similar to the following:

```
<xsl:template match="\">
   <table>
   <tr><td>
     <xsl:variable name="status" select="normal"/>
   </td></tr>
   <tr><td>
     <xsl:variable name="status" select="failed"/>
   </td></tr>
   </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Maybe it depends on browse's type. What is the standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, two variables never have the same scope. Even if they are both global, the scope of the variable excludes its own select expression, so the scope of the two variables is different.

Second, in your example the scope of the two variables isn't even overlapping. Each variable is confined to its own containing `td` element.

For two global variables, the rule is that you can have two variables with the same name provided they have different import precedence, in which case all references are treated as references to the one with higher precedence.

If one variable is local and the other is global, then the local variable wins if it is in scope.

If you have two local variables with overlapping scope, this is an error in XSLT 1.0, but is permitted in XSLT 2.0; within the overlap area, the variable with smaller scope wins.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I studied for my degree in Reading and remember it fondly.

Comment: I loved your first paragraph, it made me think of Niels Bohr and Werner Heisenberg :D

Answer (score 1):

It is an error if two or more top-level variables (outside any template) have the same name.

Similarly it is an error if two or more variables within the same template have the same name.

But it is allowable for a variable within a template to *shadow* a variable of the same name at the top level.

There is no clash between variables unless their *scopes* (the parts of the stylesheet where the variables are visible) overlap. The scope of a variable inside a template includes its following sibling elements and their descendants. The scope of a top-level variable is everywhere in the stylesheet after that variable.

Comment: What if the case the same name variables is under different node?I update the simple code.

Comment: @Ji Fang: are you sure you know what `xsl:variable` does?

Comment: I have added to my answer. Your example is fine, but note that the `status` variable is invisible outside the `<td>` element where it is declared.

Comment: Borodin's answer is correct for XSLT 1.0. For XSLT 2.0, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the key.

MSXML 3.0 supports only XDR schemas, it does not support XSD schemas. MSXML 4.0, MSXML 5.0, and MSXML 6.0 support XSD schemas.